# select cumulative sum of the difference between another cumulative sum according date and custkey

Tags: sql, database, oracle

1.only opening Balance (at the first time) ,dat and tran are from the database

2.remain and other balance are calculated based on dat and custkey at the end date of each transaction

```
 select sum(sub)  over(partition by t.custkey order by t.dat),cum,s.custkey,s.dat
    from (
    select  balance - sum(tran) over(partition by t.custkey,t.dat order by t.dat) sub ,sum(tran) over(partition by t.custkey,t.dat order by t.dat) cum ,t.custkey,t.dat
     from test t) t,test s
     where t.custkey=s.custkey
     and t.dat=s.dat
```

this is the output that i want to be

```
         dat                                               balance              tran                  remain
                                         (OpenBalance)      30

      03/01/2012                                                                    3
      03/01/2012                                                                    2
      03/01/2012                                                                    1

                                                                                                       (30-6) 24

      04/01/2012                                             6                      
      04/01/2012                                                                    2
      04/01/2012                                                                    3


                                                                                                       (6-5 + 24) 25
      05/01/2012                                             5                                                                                               2
      05/01/2012                                                                    1
      05/01/2012                                                                    5
                                                             6                                         (5-6 + 25) 24
```

Comment: Can you please arrange the look of the "output that i want to be" in your question. Also please do add the data you start with not only the data you expect to get.

Comment: @VBoka  thanks for your quick response , but this how the required output looks like , only balance=30 and dat and tran are coming from the database , the rest should be calculated.

Comment: I am not talking about the data, I am talking about the look of the data.  Is the `(OpenBalance)` name of a column? If yes, how is it possible to be under the `dat` column in results ? You have too much white spaces between the data and columns and it is hard to understand the output results. Rearrange it please. Also, again , please do add the origin data so people can understand what they have and what the query need to do just by looking on data...

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks as shown you can do this:

```
select custkey, dat, balance, tran, null remain from test
union
select custkey, dat, null, null, 
       sum(balance) over (partition by custkey order by dat) 
       - sum(tran) over (partition by custkey order by dat) 
  from test 
  order by dat, balance, tran
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dfdd4b4563c4fbafaba39e8a2f7b0caa)</sup>**

Result:

```
   CUSTKEY DAT            BALANCE       TRAN     REMAIN
---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2012-01-03          30            
         1 2012-01-03                      1 
         1 2012-01-03                      2 
         1 2012-01-03                      3 
         1 2012-01-03                                24
         1 2012-01-04           6            
         1 2012-01-04                      2 
         1 2012-01-04                      3 
         1 2012-01-04                                25
         1 2012-01-05           5            
         1 2012-01-05                      1 
         1 2012-01-05                      5 
         1 2012-01-05                                24
13 rows selected
```

If not please use dbfiddle tool and provide exact input.